# React Native can't fully hide Webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, webview, expo

I am using webview to play an mp3 file in the background. However even though I give it a width, height of zero, and an absolute position, it still covers up space and pushes other components on the screen.

```
        <WebView
        ref={(ref) => (this.webview = ref)}
        originWhitelist={["*"]}
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
        useWebKit={true}
        style={{position: "absolute", width: 0, height: 0}}
        source={{
          html:
            '<audio id="audio" loop> <source src="http://n0a.radiojar.com/bw66d94ksg8uv?rj-ttl=5&rj-tok=AAABd7AnCL0AOBTlERLEzbnm9Q" type="audio/mp3" /> </audio>',
        }}
        />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the prop `containerStyle` instead of `style`:

```js
      <WebView
        ref={(ref) => (this.webview = ref)}
        originWhitelist={["*"]}
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
        containerStyle={{ position: "absolute", width: 0, height: 0 }} // <=== your prop
        useWebKit={true}
        source={{
          html:
            '<audio id="audio" loop> <source src="http://n0a.radiojar.com/bw66d94ksg8uv?rj-ttl=5&rj-tok=AAABd7AnCL0AOBTlERLEzbnm9Q" type="audio/mp3" /> </audio>',
        }}
      />
```

Or use a view as a **container**

```js
    <View style={{position: "absolute", width: 0, height: 0}}>
      <WebView
        ref={(ref) => (this.webview = ref)}
        originWhitelist={["*"]}
        mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction={false}
        useWebKit={true}
        source={{
          html:
            '<audio id="audio" loop> <source src="http://n0a.radiojar.com/bw66d94ksg8uv?rj-ttl=5&rj-tok=AAABd7AnCL0AOBTlERLEzbnm9Q" type="audio/mp3" /> </audio>',
        }}
      />
    </View>
```